# Iterate through multidimensional PHP array/object of unknown shape

Tags: php, performance, recursion, multidimensional-array, decoding

In PHP, I'm trying to loop through a multidimensional array of unknown size and shape and decode each element. I wrote this recursive function which does the job, but it is slow for large data. I've thought about passing by reference or trying some version of array_map for multidimensional arrays. What is a more efficient way to do this?

```
function loopThroughData($data){
    if(is_array($data)){
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $data[$key] = loopThroughData($value);
        }
        return $data;
    }
    if(is_object($data)){
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $data->$key = loopThroughData($value);
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return htmlspecialchars_decode($data);
}
```

I could be thinking about it wrong and there is a better way to decode data than looping through each element.

Comment: You want to read about code profiling and then apply that to your code to see what's your real bottleneck is. Do not guess if you can measure.

Comment: Look into the php SPL recursive iterators https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php they're very cool, you create custom iterator behaviors and define how fetching children of your current iteration behavesl, then you can apply filters to the results.

Comment: I agree with Marcin, but also it is strange that you have to do this at all. The thing that is producing this source data should likely not be applying encoding like this in the first place, so if you can fix _that_ you'll likely save a lot more overhead.

Comment: @Sammitch I’m doing this on the return data from PDO fetch() because the data stored in the db is all encoded. We do this in order to avoid sql injection but perhaps there is a better way where we don’t need to encode data stored in the db.

Comment: You don't have to encode at all if you use prepared statements properly. Even excepting prepared statements, the correct approach should be to encode the data _native to the current purpose_ which would be ensuring that the SQL metacharacters are escaped and the data is inserted as intended. Sure, using other encodings may accomplish the goal in the short term, but you've set yourself up for all this needless complexity having to deal with manually decoding it afterwards.